# SSIS Remove first word in Derived Column

Tags: ssis, derived

If the word

`(xxxx) British White`

has had the (xxxx) copied to a new field, how do i write an expression to  remove (xxxx) to leave British White?

`British White`

I have experimented with trim both left and right but it only seams to remove spaces.

Comment: How do you define "first word"? What if there is only one word? Are we restricted to Derived Column only?

Comment: @billinkc No not restricted to Derived Column, but as i have just been using it recently for a ethnicity upload, it seemed appropriate to pursue on. In relation to defining a first word it depends whether or not a code in parentheses is seen as a word. There is always more than on word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Fix it in post**

Assuming you're going to SQL from a file, just stage the data in a table as-is and then fix it in your final table.

```
UPDATE 
FinalTable
SET
Column = SUBSTRING(Column, CHARINDEX( ' ' , Column) + 1 , LEN( Column ) )
```

*Pros*

- Preserve the source in case you want to do something different to it later. (This is a huge pro most people seem to gloss over.)
- SQL is generally speaking easier for others to maintain (more people grok it) and can be encapsulated in more places (stored procedure, managed code, etc.)

*Cons*

- Probably just going to stick the UPDATE statement in the SSIS package anyway.
- IO driven, if performance is an issue.

**Option 2: Derived Column**

Derived Column syntax:

```
RIGHT(Column,LEN(Column) - FINDSTRING(Column," ",1))
```

The 1 in the FINDSTRING function means use the first occurrence. If there is no space, it returns 0 and thus the expression just returns the original column.

*Pros*

- Memory-driven.
- All business logic encapsulated in package.

*Cons*

- Not preserving source.
- Have to document this somewhere outside the package so the next guy knows what's going on.